# How to check if an object is a generic type, UIHostingController

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `is` keyword with the generic `UIHostingController` class.

Basically, I want to do this:

```
let vc = window.rootViewController?.children.last { $0 is UIHostingController }
```

But it complains that `UIHostingController` needs its generic parameter `Content`. I tried using `UIHostingController<AnyView>`, which compiles but doesn't work – the actual `Content` for the controller I'm interested in is some `ModifiedContent<_etc_>` and the result is `vc == nil`.

Is there an easy way to just test for any `UIHostingController`?